# Edit colorscheme to tell me which search result my cursor is currently on

Tags: search, colorscheme

When I search for a word in my files, many of them come up, and it's tough to tell which one my cursor is currently over.

See image:

[image]

Is there a way to edit the background color for the search I'm currently on? It would be great to turn the whole word a different color, instead of just the first character. You can't see it when the screenshot tool is open, but the actual effect is that the letter `e` that's currently outlined in fact inverts the foreground and background colors. That effect is great, but any way I can apply it to the whole word?

Other ideas on how to know which one I'm on are welcome : )

Here are the current lines in my color file that might be relevant:

```
hi IncSearch    ctermfg=0   guifg=#000000 ctermbg=223 guibg=#ffdfaf cterm=none gui=none
hi Search       ctermfg=0   guifg=#000000 ctermbg=149 guibg=#afdf5f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [timakro/vim-searchant](https://github.com/timakro/vim-searchant) should do what you want:

[image]

This will set the current word red, although you can override it to some other color if you want.

Comment: Hahaa! It works, but it leaves a red stain behind after you escape the search.

Comment: @Costa That's funny. You could post a bug-report for that. I had some issues when I tried out the plugin (`n` and `*` would throw errors, etc.), but I didn't spend much time looking into it, since it could be an incompatibility with one of my other plugins. (probably `haya14busa/incsearch.vim` if I had to guess), but if itworks for you that's good.

Comment: This solved it: `let g:searchant_map_stop=0
nmap <Esc> <Plug>SearchantStop ` Help docs were sufficient : )